# Piano technique left and right hand

Tags: piano

Playing desperado after the opening there is a point in the treble clef with 4 notes. The bass clef has only one note. Can I play a treble clef note with the left hand to make it easier for my right hand to play the other 3?

Comment: It's fine to do what you're describing, but you'll get better answers overall if you upload a picture of the notes you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It's VERY common for internal voices to swap back and forth between the hands.  I'd say in more advanced music, this is the norm rather than the exception.

But you'd have to show the music for us to say whether it's a good idea in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, i would recommend practicing the four-note chords as they are much more common than you might think. Its best to get into good habits early on so you dont end up making things harder for yourself. However thats not to say that doing what you suggested is not acceptable. A lot of the time the most logical thing fingering-wise is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can reach more easily, yes. It will sound the same, and that's what matters.